# turtlebot_bringup failed to connect to iCreate

Tags: ros, usb, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I have connected ArbotiX to my turtlebot, and I'm not sure at what moment, but iCreate is no longer recognized by ubuntu.

```
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [12965]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1326474052.569072] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1326474052.570262] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1326474052.571115] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1326474052.572432] has gyro: True
shutdown request: new node registered with same name
[turtlebot_node-3] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/5f3b4ca6-3d9d-11e1-b101-485d60f51088/turtlebot_node-3*.log
```

With iCreate, Kinect and arbotix connected to Ubuntu, dmesg shows following:

```
[41790.104418] USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[41790.104717] ftdi_sio 2-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[41790.104831] usb 2-2: Detected FT232RL
[41790.104840] usb 2-2: Number of endpoints 2
[41790.104848] usb 2-2: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[41790.104855] usb 2-2: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[41790.104862] usb 2-2: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[41790.107420] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[41790.107711] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[41790.107720] ftdi_sio: v1.6.0:USB FTDI Serial Converters Driver
[42018.320055] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
[42018.535207] ftdi_sio 2-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[42018.535320] usb 2-1: Detected FT232RL
[42018.535329] usb 2-1: Number of endpoints 2
[42018.535336] usb 2-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[42018.535343] usb 2-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[42018.535349] usb 2-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[42018.537331] usb 2-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Both Usb port are used as FTDI, when only one should be. I'm not sure how does this happen, and I hope to find some help here. Thanks.

I searched here for suggestions and found similar topic http://answers.ros.org/question/3094/cant-get-data-from-create-robot-error-reading-from where I've asked for solution, but it looks like my post was removed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12629/turtlebot_bringup-failed-to-connect-to-icreate/) by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since both the arbotix and create are using FTDI chips, I'd suggest using a udev rule to assign a new dev entry for each: /dev/arbotix /dev/create or something similar based on the FTDI serial #s.

Here's what I use to differentiate my create from my arduino (you'll have to change this, but you can use the basics for reference):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI", ATTRS{product}=="FT232R USB UART", SYMLINK+="arduino"

SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI", ATTRS{product}=="US232R", SYMLINK+="create"
```

This gives me /dev/create and /dev/arduino dev entries, even though they use similar FTDI ICs. I was lucky enough that their product descriptions varried, you may find that they are the same product but have different serials.

Update: If you want to differentiate by their ID_SERIAL, it should be something like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", 
ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="FTDI", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A400C1Q6", 
SYMLINK+="create" 

SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", 
ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="FTDI", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A2001nbT", 
SYMLINK+="arbotix"
```

Stick that in a text file called `70-myrobot.rules` or something similar and throw it /etc/udev/rules.d/

Note: This is just an example and in reality you'll actually have to figure out which serial is attached to which device.  Start with one being unplugged, use `udevadm` to match the serial. Then fix the rule accordingly. The one I provided you has a 50/50 shot of being correct ;-)

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-01-13**:
You can also create a generic rule that writes the serial# in the device name: SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="sensors/ftdi_%s{serial}", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout"